# Should the database of a web application be considered an actor?

Tags: use-case

I'm just learning about use-case analysis and use-case diagrams and am a little confused whether or not the MySQL database of a web app should be considered an actor.

Is the databased considered outside of "the system" or my application, because it is its own server, most probably on another physical machine?

On the other hand, the database in a basic web application won't ever initiate a use case.

Comment: I'd say "No", but time can be an actor (triggers batch jobs for example).

Comment: That's an interesting point. …wouldn't the actor be the batch job itself and time simply its trigger?

Comment: I would always keep (batch) jobs as processes. Yes one process may trigger/start another but the ultimate actor is always the one for/by whom the initial process was initiated. If you add a task scheduler into the mix, time could indeed simply be a trigger, and the scheduler the actor, but for whom is the work being done? Who schedules the jobs? That would be a database administrator. So, I'd have the database scheduler as a process and time as the actor on behalf of the dba who would otherwise have to start the job manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database is an actor when it takes independent action -- triggers and jobs mainly.  It is not a actor when it it is simply responding to CRUD commands.